# Blazor Dialog EventCallback works without parameters but compiler throws CS1950 with parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a child dialog with a callback to the parent to open. I can get it to work if I don't have any parameters from the child being passed back to the parent but when I try to pass a boolean from child to parent I get a compile time error.

> The best overloaded Add method 'name' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments.

Now there are few details about this implementation that are playing into this difficulty.

I'm using Blazor (Net 5) and the Radzen components. [Specifically this one.](https://blazor.radzen.com/dialog)

The second parameter of the Dialog OpenAsync is a dictionary of <strings, object> where the string values are the names of the parameters on the child and the object is of course a value like a string, or even a complex object.

However, I'm trying something new in that my "object" is an EventCallback which WORKS without any additional parameters but with parameters doesn't seem to sit well with the compiler.

### The working callback without parameters

**Parent**

```
var retval = await DialogService.OpenAsync<ManageSubscriptionDialog>($"Subscription Management",
new Dictionary<string, object>() { { nameof(ManageSubscriptionDialog.SubscriptionStateChanged), UpdateSubscription } },
new DialogOptions() { Width = "600px", Height = "auto" });


private EventCallback UpdateSubscription => new(null, (Action)(async () =>
{
   //do stuff
}));
```

**Child**

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback SubscriptionStateChanged { get; set; }


//throw back to parent to handle selection
await SubscriptionStateChanged.InvokeAsync();
```

### Down the rabbit hole

**Parent**

```
var retval = await DialogService.OpenAsync<ManageSubscriptionDialog>($"Subscription Management",
new Dictionary<string, object>() { { nameof(ManageSubscriptionDialog.SubscriptionStateChanged), UpdateSubscription } },
new DialogOptions() { Width = "600px", Height = "auto" });


private EventCallback<bool> UpdateSubscription(bool isCancelled) => new(null, (Action)(async () =>
{
   //do stuff
}
```

**Child**

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> SubscriptionStateChanged { get; set; }

protected async Task InvokeSubscriptionParent(bool isCancelled)
{
    //throw back to parent to handle selection
    await SubscriptionStateChanged.InvokeAsync(isCancelled);
}
```

This won't even compile so I throw some syntax sugar in there trying to make it happy.

**Parent**

```
delegate EventCallback<bool> DelegateUpdateSubscription(bool isCancelled);
DelegateUpdateSubscription adfasdf = UpdateSubscription;
var retval = await DialogService.OpenAsync<ManageSubscriptionDialog>($"Subscription Management",
new Dictionary<string, object>() { { nameof(ManageSubscriptionDialog.SubscriptionStateChanged), adfasdf } },
new DialogOptions() { Width = "600px", Height = "auto" });

private EventCallback<bool> UpdateSubscription(bool isCancelled) => new(null, (Action)(async () =>
{
    //do stuff
}
```

**Child**

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> SubscriptionStateChanged { get; set; }

protected async Task InvokeSubscriptionParent(bool isCancelled)
{
    //throw back to parent to handle selection
    await SubscriptionStateChanged.InvokeAsync(isCancelled);
}
```

Now this compiles but at runtime when the dialog opens throws the following error.

> Unable to set property 'SubscriptionStateChanged' on object of type 'MyApp.Shared.Components.Subscription.ManageSubscriptionDialog'. The error was: Unable to cast object of type 'DelegateUpdateSubscription' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1[System.Boolean]'.

I'm not going to list everything I've tried and I am now trying to figure out how to pass a value back to the parent and I'm stumped.

### Summary

So at the end of the day all I'm trying to do is figure out how to pass parameters from child dialog back to the parent.

### Update

I now have it opening the dialog with no errors just need to figure out the last step getting the variables passed from child back to parent.

I updated my parent line of code here. I was passing null when I should have been passing the parent object as the callback handler.

**Incorrect**

```
private EventCallback<bool> UpdateSubscription => new(null, (Action)
```

**Correct**

```
private EventCallback<bool> UpdateSubscription => new(this, (Action)
```

### Final update

**Correct**

```
private EventCallback UpdateSubscription => new(this, (Action<bool>)(async (bool www) =>
```

Comment: So, do you still have a question? Post your own answer if you do (answers should not be edited into questions). You can also delete the question. If you're still looking for an answer, please clarify at the bottom of the question, what it is you're looking for

Comment: @CaiusJard I will indeed post the answer. SO makes you wait a bit before you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the compiler errors were due to some missing values and mismatched params.

Here is a working sample with a parameterized callback.

The important thing to note is that the first (string) value needs to match the name exactly in the child. The second (object) is the name of the callback in the parent.

> ParentComponent.cs

```
var retval = await DialogService.OpenAsync<ManageSubscriptionDialog($"Subscription Management",
              new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "SubscriptionStateChanged", UpdateSubscriptionHandler } },
              new DialogOptions() { Width = "600px", Height = "auto" });


private EventCallback UpdateSubscriptionHandler => new(this, (Action<UpdateSubscriptionApiModel>)(async (UpdateSubscriptionApiModel apiModel) =>
    { await UpdateSubscription(apiModel); }));
```

The UpdateSubscriptionApiModel is just a poco and I won't include it here. You could easily use a bool or string or similar.

2 items to note here.

1. The first parameter of the lambda new(this,.... This is where you will specify the receiver of the callback. Normally this would be handled under the covers for you but you need to write the lambda yourself to resolve as an "object" for the parameter dictionary.
2. The await UpdateSubscription(apiModel) is the actual method that will handle the callback.

   private async Task UpdateSubscription(UpdateSubscriptionApiModel apiModel)
   {  ...do what you need to do.... }

> Child.cs

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback SubscriptionStateChanged { get; set; }

UpdateSubscriptionApiModel model = new UpdateSubscriptionApiModel();

async Task OnManageSubscriptionSubmit()
{
    ...do whatever you need on child....
    await SubscriptionStateChanged.InvokeAsync(model);
}
```

So that's it. If I'm not clear on something post a comment and I'll respond if I can.

Comment: The callback seems to fire once the Dialog is opened and then when it's closed, so it's firing twice. Is this by design?